# How to use NSBatchUpdateRequest with dynamic values

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, core-data, nsbatchupdaterequest

I have entity called "Student" which has column called "firstName" and "lastName". My Existing entity looks like this

| firstName | lastName |
| --- | --- |
| Peter | Morgan |
| Adam | Hayden |
| Andrew | Giles |

Now, I have created a new attribute called "compositeName" which should contain joint name like "Peter Morgan", "Adam Hayden". How can I achieve this with NSBatchUpdateRequest in core data?

After batch update entity should look like this

| firstName | lastName | compositeName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | Morgan | Peter Morgan |
| Adam | Hayden | Adam Hayden |
| Andrew | Giles | Andrew Giles |

I searched for tutorials on web but I couldn't find one with dynamic values. I found solution in which NSBatchUpdateRequest contains static value

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic values via `NSExpression` in the `propertiesToUpdate` part of the expression, but unfortunately it looks like it isn't possible to perform a string concatenation using `NSExpression`.

I would question if you need this additional property at all - why not make it a calculated variable on the managed object:

```swift
extension Student {
    var compositeName: String { firstName + lastName }
}
```

This prevents you ending up with the composite name and name components getting out of sync.

An alternative approach would be to look at derived properties in Core Data, but again, they are `NSExpression` based, so string concatenation is not available.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jrturton .. I was just studying for NSBatchUpdateRequest. Most of the tutorial were updating static values with NSBatchUpdateRequest for multiple records in an entity. I was having doubt about handling dynamic values with NSBatchUpdateRequest, so I posted a question with one random example. Again, Thank you so much for your reply .